# LINQ Query two "OR" Not Working

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to select data from `ActiveDirectory` but my LINQ-query is not working.

```
DataServiceReference.Service1Client newService = new DataServiceReference.Service1Client();
            var query = from data in newService.GetAccounts()
                        where (data.SamAccountName.Contains(txtSearchBox.Text)
                        || data.GivenName.Contains(txtSearchBox.Text)
                        || data.EmailAddress.Contains(txtSearchBox.Text)) //2nd OR
                        select new { GivenName = data.SamAccountName, ID = data.ID };
            repSearchResult.DataSource = query;
            repSearchResult.DataBind();
```

When I try to add 2nd `||` the query is not working

```
The value for column 'EmailAddress' in table 'ActiveDirectory2' is DBNull.
```

But it had a data on it.

Comment: Define "not working". What does it do? What error does it give you?

Comment: Is the `EmailAddress` a string or a collection of strings?

Comment: @AD.Net it's a collection of string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
|| (data.EmailAddress == null || 
         data.EmailAddress.Any(em=> em.Contains(txtSearchBox.Text))))  //2nd OR
```

If the `EmailAddress` is a collection you should check if it contains any element that is `LIKE %searchText%`

If the collection can be null you can add a condition before the query, although it should be fine if it's run against database.

Comment: || (data.EmailAddress == null || data.EmailAddress.Contains(txtSearchBox.Text)))

Comment: @Leonel, what is the type of EmailAddress elements, if it's a `string`, it should have `.Contains`, if it's a complex type, you should figure out how to compare it, it should have some string property that holds the email address.

Comment: There's no problem in element type. I think it's a bug because LINQ can't convert null value from SQL Server so I decide to use SQLParameter in my Entity Framework and now it's working. But in other point your code is working in direct data source. thanks